# PyMongo count() deprecated, how to return document estimated number for particular query

Tags: python, mongodb-query, pymongo

Since `count()` is deprecated, How we can count documents that the query will return?

I have tried the following alternatives, but those are not really for me:

```
collection.count_documents(query)
```

This one works as expected, however is too slow on a large collection.

```
coolection.estimated_document_count
```

Has the problem that does not accept query parameters

Could you help me on finding an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be useful for someone who facing same trouble, for now I only found this approach:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/
pymongo db.command() is same as mongo db.runCommand() so:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('mongodb://xxx:xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 27017)
mongoDb = client['--DB--']
mongoDb.command({'count':"--Collection--", "query":{'field': {'$gte': 500}}})
```

tested on pymongo.version 4.0.1